# Maven Eclipse Tomcat ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, maven

I created web App Test Project using the following Maven command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.vanilla.cache -DartifactId=TestProject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After it I converted this project to Eclipse

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

After it I created new Servet named com.vanilla.test.TestServlet in eclipse and when I'm running it using Tomcat 7.0. I'm getting the following error.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vanilla.test.TestServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Please help. What am I missing?

Comment: how are you "running" it? from Eclipse? packaging the war and deploying it to Tomcat?

Comment: Does it run fine when deployed to tomcat standalone (outside Eclipse)?

Comment: @Raghuram, I have not tried to run it standalone.

Comment: This is the first test you should check to run on command line outside of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Project - > Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source .

I added /src and restarted tomcat.

Comment: Maven standard source directory is `src/main/java` .. I would recommend to move your sources there for better integration.